# Android 8.0 (touchwhiz) USB tether to Ubuntu 18.04 not being detected

Tags: usb, android, samsung, tethering

I have root (not used), and I am using the native hotspot service from Samsung. Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't detect the tethered internet. I get the following about the phone from `ip a`:

```
7: enp0s20f0u2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 16:bd:0e:3d:bd:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I am stuck at this point. Thank you for taking your time

Comment: What is the question then?

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't detect any internet from the phone.

Comment: USB tether, virtual ethernet

Comment: `ip a` and `sudo ip link show` are the same